# GAS Sort Multidimensional Array by Date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My script works sometimes and errors out sometimes. Running a debug shows that my array.sort may be the issue. This is the error:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

If it was the issue, I'm not sure why it would work sometimes and not others.

```
allData.sort(function(a,b){
  a = new Date(a[7]);
  b = new Date(b[7]);
  return a>b?-1:a<b?1:0;
});
```

Is there anything wrong with that? The 7th spot of my array contains the date and I want to sort by that.

Comment: This is the error: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

Comment: If that's the error that you're seeing in the debugger, (a) it's not your code that's at fault, it's likely a cache synchronization problem in Google's servers, and (b) it may or may not be the same thing that's causing problems in "normal" runs. Do you get the same error in notifications mailed to you when your script fails outside of the debugger?

Comment: I don't have a email trigger set up, but I can set one up and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, GAS seems to like this better:

```
allData.sort(function(a,b){return((a[7]<b[7])?-1:((a[7]>b[7])?1:0))}); 
    Logger.log(allData)
allData.reverse()
```

Now it works. Not sure why, but that's the solution.

Comment: I have question (a genuine one!).  Would the result produced by the better code be different from that produced by the following:  `allData.sort(function(a,b){return  a[7] - b[7] });` .  I got this from [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/)

Comment: David, it depends on the data being sorted. your version works for numerical values only, the other parses strings and date objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to isolate your ternary operators.

```
return a>b?-1:(a<b?1:0);
```

Comment: The commas improve readability, but are not strictly required. You'd have to be careful wrt [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), but in this example, it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Mogsdad, you have enhanced my understanding, again!

Comment: Hm, thanks. I am still getting the server error. Is this then a Google Docs issue or is my script still acting up. Again, on some days it works, but I need my spreadsheet to be more consistent. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: See @Mogsdad's comment under your question.